Is the median of an inner product of two i.i.d. random vectors non-negative?
We have two independent random vectors $X$, $Y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ with the same distribution $F$. Is it then true that
$$ \mathsf{P}\left( \left\langle X, Y \right\rangle \geq 0 \right) \geq 1/2? $$

No, this is not true. Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb R^2$ be the corners of a regular triangle centered in the origin. For example, take $a = (2, 0)$, $b = (-1, \sqrt{3})$, $c = (-1, -\sqrt{3})$. Then $\langle x, y \rangle$ for $x, y \in \{a, b, c\}$ is non-negative iff $x = y$. Take $X, Y$ to be uniformly distributed on $\{a, b, c\}$. Then the probability of $\langle X, Y\rangle$ to be non-negative is only $\frac 13$.
